# Why won't my "game runner" run?

Tags: python

Ok...So i was looking over a load of my old scripts that I wrote whilst I was learning python and I came across a game engine/runner that I wrote.

I decided to have a look over it and for some reason it won't run. What it should do is run through each level as the user types 'yes', but for some reason it gets stuck on level 1/2.

```
class Maps(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.scene_run = False

    def start(scene_run):
        print 'this function has not yet been implimented yet'


class Level_1(Maps):

    def start(self):
        print "This is the first level"

        print "do you want to complete the level?"
        choice = raw_input("> ")

        if choice == "yes":
            self.scene_run = True

        if choice == "no":
            exit(0)

class Level_2(Maps):

    def start(self):
        print "This is the second level"

        print "do you want to complete the level?"
        choice = raw_input("> ")

        if choice == "yes":
            self.scene_run = True

        if choice == "no":
            exit(0)


class Level_3(Maps):

    def start(self):

        print "This is the third level"

        print "do you want to complete the level?"
        choice = raw_input("> ")

        if choice == "yes":
            self.scene_run = True

        if choice == "no":
            exit(0)   


levelsdict = {"1": Level_1(), '2': Level_2(), '3' : Level_3()}   

class Engine(object):

    def run (self, levelsdict):

        while True:
            if levelsdict["1"].scene_run == False:
                print "level 1 not done"
                levelsdict["1"].start()

            if levelsdict["1"].scene_run == True:
                print "level 1 done"
                levelsdict['2'].start()

            elif levelsdict['2'].scene_run == True:
                print "level 2 done"
                levelsdict["3"].start()

            elif levelsdict['3'].scene_run == True:
                print "level 3 done"
                exit(0)


runner = Engine()
runner.run(levelsdict)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if levelsdict["1"].scene_run == True:
```

This is always checked first so if the user inputs yes it always gets executed and the next statements are never reached.

Try changing the `elif's to if's` to make sure they are executed each pass

You can also shorten your expressions to :

```
        while True:
            if not levelsdict["1"].scene_run: # same as ==False 
                print "level 1 not done"
                levelsdict["1"].start()

            if levelsdict["1"].scene_run: # same as ==True
                print "level 1 done"
                levelsdict['2'].start()

            if levelsdict['2'].scene_run:
                print "level 2 done"
                levelsdict["3"].start()

            if levelsdict['3'].scene_run:
                print "level 3 done"
                exit(0)
```

Comment: How would I get it to run?

Comment: @joegavin92, did you change the elif's to if's?

Comment: Ah yes I did, but now its not exiting when it gets past level 3...only if i put break to break out of the loop... surely exit(0) should work?

Comment: I tried it and it exits fine for me after reaching level 3 using python 2.7, what version of python are you using?

Comment: Hmmm this is strange, I had been using ipython notebook with python 2.7 and it kept looping. I then ran it from the terminal and it exited fine, thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. I don't think exit works on the Ipython notebook, I don't actually know if there is any way to exit without something like killing the process.